DMA I2C does not work well in stm32f10x.h
main.h
#include <stm32f10x.h>
static volatile u8 i2c_1_rx_data = 0;
static volatile u8 i2c_1_tx_data = 0;

static void i2c_1_init(void){
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio;
//Pin config for I2C_1 SCL, PB6
gpio.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_OD;
gpio.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6;
gpio.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpio);

//Pin config for I2C_1 SDA, PB7
gpio.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_OD;
gpio.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_7;
gpio.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &gpio);

RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE);
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO, ENABLE);
//GPIO_PinRemapConfig(GPIO_Remap_I2C1, ENABLE);

I2C_InitTypeDef i2c;
i2c.I2C_Ack = I2C_Ack_Enable;
i2c.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit;
i2c.I2C_ClockSpeed = 100000;
i2c.I2C_DutyCycle = I2C_DutyCycle_2;
i2c.I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C;
i2c.I2C_OwnAddress1 = 0;
I2C_Init(I2C1, &i2c);
I2C_Cmd(I2C1, ENABLE);
I2C_DMACmd(I2C1, ENABLE);

RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_DMA1, ENABLE);
DMA_InitTypeDef dma;
dma.DMA_BufferSize = sizeof(i2c_1_tx_data);
dma.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralDST;
dma.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;
dma.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = &i2c_1_tx_data;
dma.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
dma.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
dma.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Normal;
dma.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (u32)&I2C1 -> DR;
dma.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Byte;
dma.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
dma.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
DMA_Init(DMA1_Channel6, &dma);
DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel6, ENABLE);

}

main.c
#include <stm32f10x.h>
#include "main.h"

int main(){
    i2c_1_init();
    while(I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C1,I2C_FLAG_BUSY));
    I2C_GenerateSTART(I2C1, ENABLE);
    while(!I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C1,I2C_FLAG_SB));
    I2C_Send7bitAddress(I2C1, 0x52, I2C_Direction_Transmitter);
    while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_TRANSMITTER_MODE_SELECTED));
    i2c_1_tx_data = 0xC0;
    while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_TRANSMITTED));
    while(1){
    
    }
}


In my codes, i am doing about changing the way i2c transmit from polling to dma.
those code i shown above, is copied from my original code, which is in here, i just want dma works well, do not care the packet. If something is sent successfully and correctly, jobs done.
I connected the slave device to the mcu and obseved by oscilloscope, that's what i got here.
nothing behine 0x52
it should be 0xC0 regarding to my codes. it seems i2c_1_tx_data = 0xC0; does not work.
Maybe someone have concerns about dma.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = &i2c_1_tx_data;, I have another img after I change it to dma.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = i2c_1_tx_data;
huh? why 0x68? is it the address of i2c_1_tx_data?
I am totally no idea in here, why DMA read all 0s or something not related in i2c_1_tx_data, is it something wrong with the reading sequence, how codes be changed to deal this issue?
(polling is no problem for me, but a lot in DMA) :(

Does your code compile? Does STM32F1 has DMA1 channel 16? See table 78 of RM0008.

@hcheung It is channel 6, the L looks like 1, sometimes confuse others. So, yes, code can compiled. -tomertom
